# Query fields in Kibana with RegEx

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

I need to search in Kibana Logs for fields with a specific content. The field is "message", that looks like this:

> 11.111.72.58 - - [26/Nov/2020:08:44:23 +0000] "GET /images/image.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 123456 "https://website.com/questionnaire/uuid/result" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.1 Safari/605.1.14" "5.158.163.231"

This field contains URIs, for example here "https://website.com/questionnaire/uuid/result". How can I search for specific URIs in that field?
I need to get all Logs, where the field "message" contains "https://website.com/questionnaire/***someUUID****/result"
or where the URI is exactly "https://website.com/"

I've tried with Lucene:

> message:/https://.+/result/

nothing found

> message:https.*\result

URIs with "https: at the beginning found, but also returns URIs without "result" at the end

> message : "https://website.com/questionnaire" AND message : "result"

This works, but this would also work, if "result" would not be related to the URI, but would just stay alone at the end of the "message"-field. And I need something, that would really query those URIs between " ".
I need to visualise the amount of requests for each URI with Kibana later. So I think I need to use Lucene or Query DSL.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for the new [`wildcard` field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html#wildcard-field-type) (introduced in 7.9), which allows you to [better search within potentially long strings](https://www.elastic.co/blog/find-strings-within-strings-faster-with-the-new-elasticsearch-wildcard-field).

If you declare your message field as `wildcard` like this:

```
PUT test 
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "message": {
        "type": "wildcard"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then index your documents

```
PUT test/_doc/1
{
  "message": """11.111.72.58 - - [26/Nov/2020:08:44:23 +0000] "GET /images/image.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 123456 "https://website.com/questionnaire/uuid/result" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.1 Safari/605.1.14" "5.158.163.231"
  """
}
```

You can then run [`wildcard` searches](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) (even with leading wildcards which are [discouraged](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html#wildcard-query-field-params) to run on normal keyword fields) and find your document easily.

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "message": {
        "value": "*https*uuid*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I can do this only with DevTools in the Console, not in Discover > Search: 
`GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "message": {
        "value": "*https://website.com/start*"
      }
    }
  }
}`
and if I run this, then I get:
`{
  "took" : 185,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 79,
    "successful" : 79,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}`
And I think I cannot visualise that in Dashboard?

Comment: You can do it in Discover, by clicking "Add a filter" (below the search bar) and then "Edit as Query DSL" and finally adding the query in the text box

Comment: Interesting, I can search for `"value": "*https*"`, but `*https*website*` doesn't work. I think because * means zero or more "s" characters. But `*https.*website*` with the point (any character) doesn't work too.

Comment: It is discouraged to run wildcard searches with leading wildcard on `keyword` fields. Performance wise it can harm your cluster, but of course that depends on its size.

Comment: That's weird, that `"value": "s?*o?t"` works for "stream"-field => this returns all "stdout" values. But the same with "message"-field doesn't work: "https?*start" => "No results match your search criteria"